# QGIS same print layout for multiple features of a layer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, layouts

I have a layer containing hundreds of line-features, which represent flight-tracks of different bird species. The different species are defined by a column `species`, containing for example values like `species a`, `species b` and so on.

What I want to achieve is to create multiple print-maps (pdf-exports), one for each species, using the same layout from the print-composer without duplicating the layout and the layer over and over again for each species.

The Species-name is supposed to occur as a map-title. The map extent has to stay the same in every map.

The solution may be something similar to the atlas-composer, but with a map-page for each `species`, not for a spatial location...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The QGIS Atlas does not require that each page in the series be spatially distinct. In the map frame's **Item Properties**, ensure that the option **Controlled by Atlas** is *not* checked.

It does seem, however, that you have a series of attribute values, as opposed to individual features, that you want an atlas for. This can still be accomplished using an atlas, but will require a separate layer. You can easily use a standalone table for this.

Here is an example with a lines layer `Lines`, which has a `type` attribute. By using the built-in tool **List Unique Values**, you can generate a standalone table on your `type` field

[image: Lines on map]

In your **Atlas Settings**, choose the standalone table as your coverage layer, with the `type` attribute as the page name.

[image: atlas settings]

On the `Lines` layer, change the symbology to **Rule-based**. Define a single rule, using the expression `"type" = attribute(@atlas_feature, 'type')`

Now you can generate your atlas!

[image: atlas output]

Comment: That's an awesome workaround! I always merged my geometries first, but the solution of using the table is much nicer!

Comment: This works like a charme for me!

Answer (score 5):

I would create an atlas with a geom for each species (all geoms should be the same, a just a point in the same place or a boundary that defines the extent) and each geom should have an attribute with the species name. Set the atlas page name to be the atlas layer attribute. You can then use `@atlas_pagename` as the title and filename of the export of each page

Then set the symbology of the actual species layer to only show the data where the species name attribute matches the atlas pagename.

You can then export as a single atlas.

what might be easier if you don't have too many species is to manually create different layouts for each species and export all of them at once with the plugin Maps Printer.

Answer (score 0):

been trying to replicate this in my project for 2 days now. @JoshC appreciate any suggestions.

1. I have have my geometry layer with state boundary polygons.
2. I have a plain data source table with language(s) population information on each of the polygons in the first layer.
3. I have the unique languages listed in the standalone virtual table.

I have the Atlas set to use the same standalone table as the coverage layer.

When I try to set the data source (#2) layer's symbology the panel is blank. So I converted that layer to a geometry layer using fixed X,Y points. Now symbology is showing I am able to add the filter.

In the atlas, the 2 pages are for the 2 unique languages,  that is perfect, but the map shows data from both languages. I want to filter to show only one unique language. Can't get the rule based filter to work.

[image]

[image: Rule Based Filter]