# Data Driven map - Atlas, How to automate the filter feature?

Tags: qgis, python, filter, atlas

I have a Postgres data source that needs to be filtered from hundreds of records to a few records, each time a make a map.  Is there a way to automate that, so that the atlas makes map pages for each 'unique' value in the filter field.

To be specific, I have list of states/provinces in the dataset where a particular language is spoken in the country. For each new language map, currently I am filtering the data source list using the filter function on the 'language' field.

Can Python commands or the Atlas feature be used to say generate such  filtered language maps in bulk ?

[image]

Comment: MPS Atlas is long distant history, data driven pages is the Esri product that replaced it. Are you using MPS Atlas or Esri DDP? It sounds like what you're after is a dynamic definition query https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s90000003p000000 for Esri DDP, Atlas had a similar function but I'd be stretched finding any reference to that.

Comment: I am using QGIS and trying out the Atlas feature. So far I am able to generate Atlas for each province/state since that is a SHP file feature. But I am trying to see if I can so same for unique values in the data source filter fields - This case it's the language name.

Comment: Oh, that's my mistake, using data driven map I assumed you were using Esri products. This post might help https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/filtering-features-in-other-layers-of-qgis-atlas

Comment: If you use a rule in the layer styling for a layer you want to display for a page you might try "your page name" = @atlas_pagename .  If you don't want something to display you could add a rule for else.

Comment: Check out [this question / answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/375340/qgis-same-print-layout-for-multiple-features-of-a-layer/375347#375347) for a similar issue. Full disclosure, I wrote an answer to it. But it details how to create an atlas based on unique values in a layer as opposed to unique features.

Comment: Thanks @JoshC your example seems similar to the challenge I am facing, Is the 'Lines'  Layer the one that is the SHP layer ?  I understand that 'Types' is the one with the unique values in a a standalone table

Comment: The "Lines" layer in that example would be the layer with many records which needs to be filtered to a few in each atlas page.

Comment: Thanks,  I tried and have added comments on that example, page. Having some trouble with adding the rule based symbology.